# How can I succinctly (and temporarily) turn a button into a tab toggler?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

Look at this code. It's inside a jQuery event listener. `$(this)` is a `<form>` element

```js
            const submitButton = $(this).find('[type=submit]');

            submitButton.removeClass('btn-primary')
                .addClass('btn-success')
                .attr('value', 'User added!')
                .attr('type', 'button');

            setTimeout(function () {
                submitButton.removeClass('btn-success')
                    .addClass('btn-primary')
                    .attr('value', 'Submit')
                    .attr('type', 'submit')
            }, 9000);
```

On submit, the submit button becomes green, displays a "User added" text and then, after eight seconds, becomes a regular submit button again. I want it to be able to activate the "users-table" tab on click while it's still green

First, I tried this

```js
.attr('onclick', '$(\'#users-table\').tab(\'show\')')
```

It *kind of* worked, but the tab was displayed on top of the already displayed tab and the nav tabs didn't change either

[image]

I then tried adding a new event listener

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add-new-user').on('click', '.btn-success', function () {
        $('[href="#users-table"]').tab('show');
    });
});
```

It worked, but it's *not* succinct

**How can I achieve my objective?** I would like to avoid manually deactivating the `add-new-user` tab and activating the `users-table` tab button (and then reversing it on timeout)

It seems "similar" questions here on SO don't answer my question

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Admin Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#users-table">All Users</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#add-new-user">Add New User</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
       </div>
            <div class="row tab-content">
            <div id="users-table" class="tab-pane container active">
            <table class="table table-hover text-center">
                      <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Last name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Department</th>
                            </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>John</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>IT</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Jane</td>
                                <td>Doe</td>
                                <td>HR</td>
                            </tr>
                     </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
           <div id="add-new-user" class="tab-pane container">
              <h3>Fill in the forms</h3>
                              <form>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="name">Name: </label>
                                      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" required />
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="last-name">Last name: </label>
                                      <input id="last-name" name="last-name" type="text" class="form-control" required />
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <label for="department">Department: </label>
                                      <select id="department" name="department" class="form-control">
                                          <option value="IT">IT</option>
                                          <option value="HR">HR</option>
                                          <option value="accounting">Accounting</option>
                                      </select>
                                  </div>

                                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary d-flex ml-auto" value="Submit" />
                              </form>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('form').on('submit', async function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('tbody').append(
    `<tr>
         <td>
             ${$(this).find('[name=name]').val()}
         </td>
         <td>
             ${$(this).find('[name=last-name]').val()}
         </td>
         <td>
             ${$(this).find('[name=department]').val()}
         </td>
     </tr>`
    );
            const submitButton = $(this).find('[type=submit]');

            submitButton.removeClass('btn-primary')
                .addClass('btn-success')
                .attr('value', 'User added!')
                .attr('type', 'button');

            setTimeout(function () {
                submitButton.removeClass('btn-success')
                    .addClass('btn-primary')
                    .attr('value', 'Submit')
                    .attr('type', 'submit')
            }, 8000);
});
});
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Also, how can I also reset the _non-hidden_ forms on timeout in one go? It's a bit off-topic, but you can answer it too, if it's not very complicated

Comment: One possiblility would be to `.click()` the required tab elements.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK if you mean this, `.attr('onclick', '$([href=\'#users-table\']).click()')`, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I believe @Haroldo_OK meant `$(this).find("href=\'#users-table\'"]).click()`

Comment: @RuanMendes why doesn't `.attr('onclick', '$([href=\'#users-table\']).click()')` work?

Comment: @RuanMendes that's the whole point. I want the submit button to become a tab toggler for a short while. So that you can click it again and see the new user in the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector to show the users-table was wrong, it should be `$('[href="#users-table"]')` instead of `$("#users-table")`

I would avoid setting handlers with `attr`. That forces you to have to escape content and makes your code hard to read. Just use `.click(() => $('[href="#users-table"]').tab('show'));` and `.off('click')` to remove the handlers.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', async function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('tbody').append(
      `<tr>
         <td>
             ${$(this).find('[name=name]').val()}
         </td>
         <td>
             ${$(this).find('[name=last-name]').val()}
         </td>
         <td>
             ${$(this).find('[name=department]').val()}
         </td>
     </tr>`
    );
    const submitButton = $(this).find('[type=submit]');

    submitButton.removeClass('btn-primary')
      .addClass('btn-success')
      .attr('value', 'User added!')
      .attr('type', 'button')
      .click(() => $('[href="#users-table"]').tab('show'));

    setTimeout(function() {
      submitButton.removeClass('btn-success')
        .addClass('btn-primary')
        .attr('value', 'Submit')
        .attr('type', 'submit')
        .off('click');

    }, 8000);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Admin Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mb-2">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#users-table">All Users</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#add-new-user">Add New User</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row tab-content">
      <div id="users-table" class="tab-pane container active">
        <table class="table table-hover text-center">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Last name</th>
              <th scope="col">Department</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>John</td>
              <td>Doe</td>
              <td>IT</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Jane</td>
              <td>Doe</td>
              <td>HR</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="add-new-user" class="tab-pane container">
        <h3>Fill in the forms</h3>
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control" required />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="last-name">Last name: </label>
            <input id="last-name" name="last-name" type="text" class="form-control" required />
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="department">Department: </label>
            <select id="department" name="department" class="form-control">
              <option value="IT">IT</option>
              <option value="HR">HR</option>
              <option value="accounting">Accounting</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary d-flex ml-auto" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's not what I want. I want the green button to become the toggler while it's still green

Comment: You mean that if they click the button that says User added it would show the tab? Sounds very unintuitive. Dynamically setting handlers is pretty confusing, I'll update the answer to do what you want but will warn you that it feels very confusing.

Comment: If that's the case, the problem is that you had the wrong selector, you need to call `tab` on the a tag, not the wrapper. `$('[href="#users-table"]').tab('show');` instead of `$('#users-table')`

Comment: I think it's very intuitive that if you click "User added", you get to see the added user in the table

Comment: We are allowed to disagree. A button should have an action as its text, even using the button to show that the user was added feels like you are misusing the button. Having said that, I'm glad I understood what you meant, we found what the problem was, and I was able to suggest a clearer way of doing it.